# Blazor Server shows empty page in modern browsers

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am running a blazor server website at http://dev.softwaretechnik.it

Unfortunately the following are the minimum browser version requirements.

- Firefox 78 (2020-06-30 !!) (current is 84)
- Edge 80 (2020-02-07 !!) (current is 87)
- Opera 53 (2018-05-12 !) (current 71)
- Chrome 66 (2018-04-17 !) (current 87)

Older versions will just show a blank page. What?!

**Could it be caused by css isolation feature of NET 5?**

EDIT: see my answer below.

The site is an open source community project hosted at GitHub.

_Host.cshtml: https://github.com/CleanCodeX/WebApp.SoE/blob/main/Pages/_Host.cshtml

Startup.cs: https://github.com/CleanCodeX/WebApp.SoE/blob/main/Startup.cs

The rest is pretty much standard.

Any clues what's going wrong here?

Comment: And what do the dev tools show you?  Any 404s or errors in the console?

Comment: It says: https://i.ibb.co/ZmxSJgS/Uncaught-Error.png
For blazor.server.js line 1. that's most likely not the error.
I tried adding polyfill afterwards but same result. (helps only for IE, but not for ES6 which causes the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curious, although firefox 77 cannot load  blazor.server.js, the below script says that it supports a bunch of ES6 features.

What feature is Firefox lacking which prevents loading Blazor lib?

```
function HasEs6Support() {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof Symbol == "undefined") return false;
    try {
        // Arrow functions support
        () => {};

        // Class support
        class __ES6FeatureDetectionTest {
        };

        // Object initializer property and method shorthands
        let a = true;
        let b = {
            a,
            c() {
                return true;
            },
            d: [1, 2, 3],
        };

        // Object destructuring
        let { c, d } = b;

        // Spread operator
        let e = [...d, 4];

        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

furthermore, according to the featurelist at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

there is NO difference between firefox 77 and 78. But the difference is, 78 loads the page correctly, where 77 does not.

I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if someone still has this problem, but I had a similar issue and after looking at my code, I was using a layout but not calling @Body in it.
In my case it was the mainLayout.

Comment: Can you add more details ? The question doesn't talk about a `mainLayout` so please [edit] your answer to explain more ! :)